# twitter bootstrap 3++ modal window doesn't load

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

My twitter bootstrap modal window isn't loading properly; it is faded when it loads. [Here is an image demonstrating the problem](http://postimg.org/image/b5be5m0t9/).

I have tried a few things but cannot resolve the issue.

My code is:

```
<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-mini\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\" href=\"#myModal\">

 <div id=\"myModal\" class=\"modal fade\">
        <div class=\"modal-dialog\">
            <div class=\"modal-content\">
                <div class=\"modal-header\">
                    <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class=\"modal-title\">Confirmation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class=\"modal-body\">
                    <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                    <p class=\"text-warning\"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class=\"modal-footer\">
                    <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">Close</button>
                    <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: You can't use `href` on a `<button>`. Validate your HTML!

Comment: What error do you see in browser's console? (F12 button). Also why all of your quotes are escaped?

Answer (score 1):

There's invalid syntax in your code example (HTML and Bootstrap). It seems like you're trying to load a warning button before the modal, but you're missing text for the button as well as the closing button tag. Here's a Bootstrap 3 example that should accomplish what you described:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal">
     Save Now!
</button>
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                    <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Edit the button text to read what you'd like. "Save Now!" is just an example for illustration purposes.